# What's your favorite book?

Tags: discussion, users

Most people, upon confessing that they love books, are immediately met with that question  about what their favorite book is. We recently [shared our answers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037/2024/3/18) to it in chat; turns out, most of the favorites were a bit unexpected. I guess it makes sense, considering the breadth of the works discussed on this site, and how well-read most people here are. Still, chat messages are restricted to five hundred characters, so nuances and details and caveats and extra suggestions are left out. That's useful for if we want a snappy sort of thing, but less useful for making a more thoughtful list of works that people here have read and loved.

I think Mithical's right [in saying](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65358552#65358552) that it's easier to pick favorites in each genre, so I think multiple offerings are fine, and even encourage-able. Perhaps having such a collection might prompt conversations, motivate topic challenges, or inspire questions; at the very least, it'll stave off boredom. (I guess it might intensify the issue if your to-be-read pile—or shelf, or bookcase—is already massive, but 'you can never have too much to read.' Or some such platitude.)

**What are your favorite books, and why?**

---

<sub><sup>Those who answered in chat, feel free to repost here and expand, if you want to.</sup></sub>

Comment: Fyi, in chat you can post the message to the limit and then continue typing in the textbox. When you hit send, it appends to the previous message. So, there really is no limit to length. You just keep typing in a new text box. Take a look at chat on the French site. They post very long messages, for example.